# Fortran compile error: makefile recipe for target '../lib/libSPheno.a(Mathematics.o)' failed

Tags: fortran, makefile

I am using a package and modified a SPheno4.F90 file in src folder. When I tried compile using make in src,

```
make: Warning: Archive '../lib/libSPheno.a' seems to have been 
created in deterministic mode. 'Control.o' will always be updated. 
Please consider passing the U flag to ar to avoid the problem.
Control.F90
make: Control.F90: Command not found
Makefile:86: recipe for target '../lib/libSPheno.a(Control.o)' failed
make: *** [../lib/libSPheno.a(Control.o)] Error 127
```

where in the makefile,

```
InDir = ../include
Mdir = ${InDir}
name = ../lib/libSPheno.a

ifeq (${F90},gfortran)
comp = -c -O -J${Mdir} -I${InDir}
LFlagsB = -O  
endif

.SUFFIXES : .o .ps .f90 .F90 .a
bin/SPheno: ${name} SPheno4.o
${F90} -o SPheno ${LFlagsB} SPheno4.o ../lib/${name}
mv SPheno ../bin
${name}: ${name}(Control.o)  ${name}(Mathematics.o)  ${name}(RGEs.o)\
```

...

```
.f90.a:
${F90} ${comp} $<
ar -ruc $@ $*.o
rm -f $*.o
```

...
while in ../lib folder, there is only a single file, libSPheno.a.

I totally have no idea about this error.
In fact, I don't understand each line in this makefile hence any advice for this kind of debugging is also welcome.

Comment: ... and the rule for the .F90 file ?

Comment: Oh i just solved it by changing compiler opt. in makefile.

Comment: In what way dit you change the options. There is often a difference between .f90 and .F90 files (last ones to be preprocessed by the C/Cpp preprocessor).

Comment: Ah.. I made a typo in OP. I modified .f90 file and I just added F90=gfortran